# How to resize the viewport of a Jscrollpanewhile it is visible?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm having a issue resizing the jpanel in a jscrollpane while it is visible. Here is my code:

```
for (String Id : SearchResultsMap.keySet())
        {
            JButton IdPanelButton = CreateIdPanelButton(Id);

            IdListPanel.add(IdPanelButton);
            IdPanelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    ClearRecordDetails();
                    setRecordDetails(SearchResultsMap.get(Id));
                }
            });
        }
        IdListPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(IdListPanel.getWidth(), (int) (SearchResultsMap.size()* CreateIdPanelButton("").getHeight())));
        IdListPanel.validate();
```

What I'm basically doing is generating a list of buttons for the user to click on that will then display some information. The CreatIdPanelButton just create a new jbutton with visual constraints. The issue im having is that the IdListPanel is not resizing even though i tried setting the preferred size. I also tried revalidating the jscrollpane and that is not working. Anyone have any idea to update the jscrollpane viewport while it is visible??

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the issue, when you first create a Jbutton it takes sometime before the actual Height is set and computed,  so the getHeight method of the jbutton was returning 0 because it had not been set as it yet. So I fixed it by adding a constant of jbutton target height

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you have initialized a specified size, try to specify a size.

If that isnt it, you need to show the code you referenced because there might be some bug elsewhere and i cant see it.

Comment: I did call setpreferredsize when I originally created it, so can you not update the size after you call that?

Comment: It needs to be updated live several times because i'm essentially creating a search system.

Comment: why dont you set JPanel to max and use JScroll?

Comment: no, you havent set the dimensions of the JPanel so when trying to change the dimentions with respect to the previous dimensions, it doesnt know how much that is, it creates a panel of random size

Comment: What do you mean set max size @noel

Comment: what is the maximum size of the panel you are ever gonna use

Comment: also use these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812980/how-to-use-the-jscrollpane-in-java     https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: I know how to use scroll panes but i will try the jlist and let you know if that works

Comment: just tried it and it didnt work JList arent meant to be used with jbuttons just primitive types like strings and so on, just research that.